# Add CORS policy for Swagger Endpoints Only

Tags: .net-core, swagger, openapi

I would like to add cors to swagger.json but not to the controller endpoints.  I am able to make a cross-site call when I add a cors policy globally using.

```
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("SwaggerCorsPolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader();
                }));
```

along with

`app.UseCors("SwaggerCorsPolicy");`

With this in place I can call `/swagger/v1/swagger.json` from another port, so I know it's working.

I'd like to add cors only to the endpoint `/swagger/v1/swagger.json`.

I have tried using `MapGet` in the `app.UseEndpoints` but I have not been successful.  Here is what I tried

```
            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapGet("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", async context => context.Response.WriteAsync("echo"))
                    .RequireCors("SwaggerCorsPolicy");
            });
```

I'm running is to issues when I produce the swagger.json from the applicaiton and run ReDoc in a container passing in the localhost uri of the swagger.json.  It works when the cors is enabled globally, but not when I try to enable it just for swagger.json.

I'm using .net core 3 and openapi 3.

Comment: Did you find anything ? I also only find how to enable cors for the whole application but not for swagger.json only. It's a security breach to enable cors for the whole API if you don't need it.

Comment: also posted here https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2078

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a CORS rule based on the controller methods, read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enable-cors-with-attributes

Once you define a policy you can attach it to individual methods. Although, I'm not sure why you would need CORS specific policies for Swagger. Swagger is just the user interface for the API methods you've configured.

I don't foresee anyone trying to pull your Swagger from another origin. To be clear, you can't just set CORS policies for the API methods when you're in Swagger. Swagger is just an interfacing tool for the API's.

Comment: I'm not using swaggerUI. I'm using Redoc and passing in the /swagger/v1/swagger.json. I am running into the CORS issue when I run ReDoc for the UI in a container which runs through a different port than the api. I pass the /swagger/v1/swagger.json documentation uri  to Redoc. When I enable CORS gloabally for all endpoints I don't get the CORS error.  I want to be able to enable it only for /swagger/v1/swagger.json.   The documentation you provided, is how I got to the original implementation in the question.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work as implemented above.